# Selecting specific columns with SQLAlchemy inheritance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using the example from the SQLAlchemy documentation for inheritance, how would I query the `Employee` class for only the `id` and `engineer_info` columns of all derived classes, including ones which don't have the `engineer_info` column?

```py
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type,
    }

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    engineer_info = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
    }

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    manager_data = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'manager',
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do this if you explicitly join the `employee` table to `engineer` table in a `left`/`outer` join, like:

```py
session.query(Employee.id, Engineer.engineer_info).join(Engineer, isouter=True).all()
```

or:

```py
session.query(Employee.id, Engineer.engineer_info).outerjoin(Engineer).all()
```

---

For future searchability: See also [SQLAlchemy inheritance filter on all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561562/sqlalchemy-inheritance-filter-on-all-columns) which I found by googling "sqlalchemy left join subclass"