# Dynamic importing of registered subclasses stored in various modules

Tags: python, oop, import, python-import, metaprogramming

Please consider the following derived script structure:

```python
import abc

class BaseMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    __registry__ = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        if bases:
            BaseMeta.__registry__.update({ cls.__name__: cls })

        # other modifications of namespaces

        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)


class Base(metaclass = BaseMeta):

    pass  # Various abstract properties and methods


class Derived0(Base): pass


class Derived1(Base): pass

# ...

class DerivedN(Base): pass
```

The code above was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882155/10286751) answer; I cannot use `__subclass__` because I need to track direct as well as indirect subclasses. While I can circumvent this requirement for now, I would like to keep it for forward compatibility.

I would like to dynamically dispatch these subclasses using `__getattr__()` from the `Base.__registry__`.  Because these subclasses can grow to several hundreds of SLOC and can depend on dozens of files, primarily SQL schemas, I would like to organize them into packages, e.g.

```bash
__main__.py
gui  # Irrelevant package
db  # Irrelevant package
# [...] Other irrelevant packages
relevant
    __init__.py  # Contains Base
    derived0
        __init__.py  # Contains Derived0 and related machinery
    derived1
        __init__.py  # Contains Derived1 and relevant machinery and imports module-xxx.py
        module-xxx.py
        schema_main.sql
        copy-query-.xxx.sql
        # [...]
    # [...]
```

The problem is then that we would need to *import* dynamically as well. The only solution that I am aware of is to use `pkgutil` to walk the packages and `exec(compile())` the buffers. This, however, messes up the namespaces.

I believe this problem to be somewhat analogous to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787291/dynamic-importing-of-modules-followed-by-instantiation-of-objects-with-a-certain) one, which seems as idiomatic as code for such problems can get, but I do not know result in *exactly* the same behavior as a simple import from a parent package? Does anyone know how to solve this?

All help is more than welcome, and so is other critique of the above code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem using `pkgutil`, `importlib`, and `pathlib` like so:

```py
import abc
import importlib
import pathlib
import pkgutil 


class BaseMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    __registry__ = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        if bases:
            BaseMeta.__registry__.update({ cls.__name__: cls })

        # other modifications of namespaces

        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)


class Base(metaclass = BaseMeta):

    pass  # Various abstract properties and methods


# Subclasses have now been moved to their respective subpackages

for parent_FF, name, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(
        name,
        (pathlib.Path(parent_FF.path) / name / "__init__.py").as_posix()).load_module()
```

Because the way Python handles paths is highly non-standardized, I am unaware of any more elegant solutions.